# How to sort context menu elements in a TreeView in a VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I build a [Git Flow Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Serhioromano.vscode-gitflow).

In my actions inside view, context menus are sorted alphabetically.

[image]

I want them to be sorted as in the order I entered commands in configuration. How can I control order? I can see that the same action menu of git is well organized yet has separators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you have to add them to a group and number the entries

```
  "menus": {
    "view/title": [
      {
        "command": "myExt.cmd1",
        "when": "view == myView",
        "group": "mygr@1"
      },
      {
        "command": "myExt.cmd2",
        "when": "view == myView",
        "group": "mygr@2"
      },
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Amazing. It is nowhere stated in documentation. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Do you know how to show badge with number of child elements?

Comment: @SergeyRomanov where is this badge

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/orpz6hzpcty5c4s/2022-02-01_19-51-08.png?dl=0

Comment: @SergeyRomanov I think this the TreeView++ available only to the VSC team, if you want this functionality you have to write a WebviewView and do it all yourself

Comment: Cool! This also works for the tree view context menu items.